# How to label or categorize git commits

Tags: git

I have a number of pieces of information that I would like to add to a commit. This information is for both automated and manual processes. Examples include a team's name, a status (generated, development, configuration, etc), or a ticket number.

Is there a way to add this information to the commits or do I have to tag akin to `TICKET-1234:<HASH>`?

Comment: Is that existing commit or a new one? You can always add any information you want in the commit description. It is common practice to add ticket number for example and most system know to link it to the ticket

Answer (score 7):

There are a number of available options:

- If all you want is to short, memorable name for a commit, you can simply tag it using [`git tag`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag). A tag object points to a commit and contains an additional message, and is itself named by a ref with a prefix of `refs/tags/`. By default, the `fetch` and `push` operations will not synchronise tags with a remote repository unless you pass `--tags`.
- If you need to store information at commit creation time, you can include it at the bottom of the the commit message in RFC822-like header:

  ```
  Fixes: ticket #1234
  ```

  The `git commit` command even provides a built-in `--signoff` option that adds one such header automatically.
- If you need to store longer-form information that changes over time, take a look at [`git notes`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-notes):

  > Adds, removes, or reads notes attached to objects, without touching the objects themselves.
  >
  > By default, notes are saved to and read from `refs/notes/commits`, but this default can be overridden. See the OPTIONS, CONFIGURATION, and ENVIRONMENT sections below. If this ref does not exist, it will be quietly created when it is first needed to store a note.
  >
  > A typical use of notes is to supplement a commit message without changing the commit itself. Notes can be shown by git log along with the original commit message. To distinguish these notes from the message stored in the commit object, the notes are indented like the message, after an unindented line saying "Notes (<refname>):" (or "Notes:" for `refs/notes/commits`).

  Like tags, by default refs with the `refs/notes/` prefix are not synchronised by `fetch` and `push` operations. You'd have to additionally configure git to keep track of them.