# How to add metadata info to a git commit

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-log

I am working on some git tooling that helps prevent git conflicts. Git commit authors are usually identified by their email address, but many people have multiple email addresses. Instead I would like to use a uuid to identify each committer, and my goal is to somehow include that uuid in the git commit metadata somehow. Is there some way to configure git to include that uuid or is not really possible?

I would assume the only place the uuid could go is the git commit message and that would make them quite noisy?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to label or categorize git commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60247008/how-to-label-or-categorize-git-commits)

Comment: Why isn’t the email or name a good identifier, and how would this prevent conflicts? After all, that’s is what git blame uses.

Comment: Because there are multiple emails and names for the same person, all of which I cannot know in advance, but the uuid I could know in advance. Given the way my idea works now. So I would want to add the uuid to the git commit somehow.